# In JPA, insert a child and save and remove the child immediately does not remove the child in database

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I have a Parent entity contains a list of Childs.

- Parent A contains Child A1
- In Transaction

  - Add Child A2 to the child list
  - Save (without Flush)
  - Clear the child list (by clear collection)
  - Add Child A3
  - Save and Flush

In the result:

- There are two Child records in database: (A1 is removed)

  - A2 with no Parent info (==null)
  - A3 with Parent info

Can someone point me a document to show how JPA works not to add Parent info for A2?

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    List<Child> children;

    @Version
    private Long recordVersion;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @Version
    private Long recordVersion;

    public String toString() {
        return "Child[id=" + id + ";name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

```
@Transactional
    public void addChild(Long parentId, String childName) {
        Parent parent = getParent(parentId);

        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("A2");
        List<Child> children = Arrays.asList(child);
        parent.getChildren().addAll(children);
        parentRepository.save(parent);

        parent = getParent(parentId);
        parent.getChildren().clear();

        Child child1 = new Child();
        child1.setName("A3");
        List<Child> spaces1 = Arrays.asList(child1);

        parent.getChildren().addAll(spaces1);
        parentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);
    }
```

Update 1:
if I comment out parentRepository.save(parent); or replace by parentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);, there is only A3 in the database.

Comment: what underalining implementation are you using for JPA, In case of Hibernate there is a bug in Hibernate resulting the behavior you explained https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12210?jql=creator%20in%20(currentUser())%20order%20by%20created%20DESC

Comment: @MikhailChibel, I used Hibernate. However, I cannot map the bug to my issue, could you give more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for the issue you're facing is that the bidirectional association is not mapped correctly. In fact, you've declared two completely unrelated associations, and then you made them share the join column.

To properly map a bidirectional one-to-many association, you need to declare the 'one' side as being the inverse side like so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
List<Child> children;
```

Note that, in such a scenario, `Child` is the owning side of the association. Changes to `Parent.children` are completely ignored.

Since you seem to want to be able to manage the association using `Parent.children` exclusively, you'll probably want to make `Parent` the owning side by removing the `Child.parent` property instead (thus changing the association to a unidirectional one).

Note that the two above options are the only valid mappings. You cannot simultaneously make both sides of an association the owning side, and in a bidirectional one-to-many association, the 'one' side **cannot** be the owning side.

Comment: I follow section 6.3 in the article https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: Well, the section says 'this is not a recommended practice', and your case is an example why